# Fastest known way to computing the $n$-th Fibonacci number?

Tags: algorithms, fibonacci-numbers

Using the recursive formula and a bit of memory, you can compute this number in linear time.

But there is also the direct formula. Unfortunately, it used irrational numbers, so first need to fix an adequate ring in which you do the computations (like the rationals and $\sqrt5$). Then you need to compute and subtract the powers of the irrational numbers. So it is not obvious how many steps you really need.

Or is there an even faster way?

Comment: Really hard to beat a closed formula.   And you only really need the lead term, the other is minor rounding.

Comment: The closed formula needs powers of irrational numbers. To get the exact integer result you need to be careful with the precision, and anyway there are $O(\log n)$ multiplications. I don't think it's any better than the binary method.

Comment: I agree Jean-Claude

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172257/efficient-calculation-of-fibonacci-series) similar question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Since $F_n$ has $O(n)$ digits in it, your model of computation matters.  Repeatedly squaring the matrix $\pmatrix{1&1\\1&0}$ will take $O(\log n)$ matrix multiplies; each will naively cost $O(n^2)$ bit ops in a multiprecision implementation.

Comment: Are you computing the exact value or are you working modulo something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several approaches that take $O(\log n)$ arithmetic operations. (Although the cost of doing operations on numbers the size of $F_n$ shouldn't be neglected either: the Fibonacci numbers grow exponentially, so $F_n$ takes $O(n)$ bits to store. But this cost will be roughly the same for any method you use.)

Probably the simplest one to explain is to write the Fibonacci recurrence relation as the matrix product $$\begin{bmatrix}F_{n} \\ F_{n-1}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}F_{n-1} \\ F_{n-2}\end{bmatrix}$$
from which we get
$$\begin{bmatrix}F_n \\ F_{n-1}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}^{n-1}\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}.$$
To compute $A^{n-1}$ quickly for a matrix $A$, we can use iterated squaring: the recurrence $$A^k = \begin{cases}(A^{k/2})^2 & \text{$k$ even, } \\ A \cdot A^{k-1} & \text{$k$ odd. }\end{cases}$$

Comment: "Although the cost of doing operations on numbers the size of $F_n$ shouldn't be neglected either" - in fact, since $F_n$ is exponential in $n$ it has $O(n)$ digits, so merely *writing down the answer* (including to computer memory) at the end guarantees the whole process takes at least $O(n)$ time. Of course, some complexity definitions exclude certain costs or treat them as $O(1)$.

Comment: Writing down the answer takes $O(n)$ time, but the greatest cost will be paid in the last squaring operation we do, which requires multiplying together two $O(n)$-digit numbers. I'm willing to neglect this here, not because it's irrelevant, but because it will be a factor in any algorithm, one way or the other.

Answer (score 3):

The formula $$F_{2n+1}=F_{n+1}^2+F_n^2\\F_{2n}=F_n(2F_{n+1}-F_n)$$ is also $\log(n) $ this identity follows by using the matrix Misha wrote and writing $A^{2n}=A^nA^n$